# Simpliest way to build a multi-dimensional array with SQL result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently building a web planning and I want to show some data in the period display.

I have a PHP file where I create my SQL request over ~13 tables and fetch all results (I use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), then I have to loop over my result to build the array I want.

The problem is I need to build a complicated array with lot of data. Here is the kind of result I want to achieve :

```
$result = array(
  $place_1 => array(
    'data_place' => array(
      'id' => ...,
      'name' => ...,
      // etc.
    ),
    'data_target' => array(
       $target_type_1 => array(
         $name_1 => ...,
         $name_2 => ...,
         // etc.
       ),
       $target_type_2 => array ( ... ),
       // etc.
    ),
    'data_isOpen' => array(
       $day_1 => array(
         $hour_begin => ...,
         $hour_end => ...
       ),
       $day_2 => array ( ... ),
       // etc.
    ),
    'data_box' => array(
      // same kind of stuff with more dimension
    )
  ),
  ...
  $place_n = array(
    // same
  )
);
```

When I execute my request, I get something like 3000 array with all the data I need, but I only have 29 places in database so there is a lot of repetition...

```
$result = array(
  0 => array(
    "id" => ...,
    "name" => ...,
    // the list of all fields I need in my big array
  ),
  ...
  n => array(
    // same 
  )
);
```

I almost manage to achieve the result I want with some "foreach" and headaches but here is my question :

**Is it possible to build a SQL request and fetch the result as I want? I mean, can I group all the result by "id_place" for example but wihtout lost information? And if it's possible, can we do it multiple time?**

The idea is to get a result with one array for every place (so 29 and not 3000), then for every "place array", group for example the "hour_begin" and "hour_end" by "opening_day", etc...

Sorry if it's a duplicate, I didn't saw any positive anwser to my question so I try again !

Comment: If you get 3000 results and you only want 29, you need to modify the sql, not the php.

Comment: SQL itself will not return a result with an array like you are talking about.  You will need to use PHP to build an array like the one you described OR you can use an ORM like Eloquent that comes with Laravel to build objects and relations from the results.

Comment: @jeroen Well, this is my question : how can I group my result without lost any information? My SQL request use 13 differents tables so it's normal if I have that much results. For example : 1 "place" have n "opening_day" so I have n result for the same place. And it's just ONE example with 2 tables, as I said I have 13 tables with different kind of relation

Comment: @kyle Ok...this is what I thought but I wanted to know if there is an easiest way, I'm sure I'm not the only one with this kind of problem ! They don't use Laravel where I work but I will take a look in "Eloquent", ty :)

Comment: Depending on the type of data in the tables and how consistent/safe to manipulate it is - you could use functions like IFNULL or GROUP_CONCAT to reduce the number of results by delimiting them, then parse those results with the PHP script - but it sounds like you're working with something fairly complicated so really folks would need to see an example, e.g. on http://sqlfiddle.com/